# Setting Background of TextArea

Tags: css, textarea, javafx-8

I would like to provide for user possiblity to select color of TextArea:

```
private void updateTextArea(){
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #" + textColor + "; -fx-background-color: #" + backgroundColor);
    }
```

however this doesnt change color of whole background. Ive found on the Internet that to change backgroud of text Area I need to do something like this in external CSS file.

```
.text-area .content {  
   -fx-background-color: black ;  
}
```

how Can I do this with setStyle()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by fetching the content node out of the `TextArea` and applying the style to it. But it works only after the `TextArea` is *shown on the stage*.

**Usage :**

```
Node node = textArea.lookup(".content");
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
```